# How to rename a GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github

Without modifying too much stuff, I am wondering how I can rename the repository name? Say, from `foo` to `bar`?

Any command to achieve this?

Comment: You just rename the top folder of your project

Answer (score 7):

1. Click on `Settings`, from the github page for your repository.
2. Give it a new name, and click on `Rename`.

Keep in mind that renaming doesn't preserve any links or redirects; so people going to your old repository link will get the famous 404 page of github.

In addition, you will still have to rename your local copy of the repository. Type `git remote -v` to see all the remotes for your local copy and then `git remote set-url <name> <new-url>` to update the links.

If you just want to discard you local copy and start fresh, simply re-clone it from github using the new URL.

Comment: official documentation here: https://help.github.com/articles/renaming-a-repository/